# Rolling window to calculate Value at Risk in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, quantitative-finance, rolling-computation

I'm sure this is very obvious but i'm a begginer in R and i spent a good part of the afternoon trying to solve this...

I'm trying to create a rolling window to calculate the Value at Risk (VaR) over time.

I already calculated the unconditional VaR for my entire timeserie of 7298 daily returns.

Now, what i'm trying to do is do a rolling window that calculates VaR for a window of 25 days that will roll every one observation for my entire timeserie.

I tried

```
apply.rolling(nas, trim = TRUE, gap = 25, by = 1, FUN = function(x) VaR(R = nas, p = 0.99, method="historical"))
```

and

```
rollapply(nas, width = 25, FUN = function(x) VaR(R = nas, p = 0.99, method="historical"))
```

where `nas` is my time serie.

My code still runs from an hour ago... I don't know what I did wrong...

Thank you very much in advance for any help you can provide.

H.

Comment: could you try data.table::frollapply? It's supposed to be very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
rollapply(nas, width = 25, FUN = function(x) VaR(R = x, p = 0.99, method="historical"))
```

Basically you applying a function that takes in value `x` (which is a filtered `nas` to 25 time units), and produces output based on the `x`. In your original attempt, the function was `function(x) VaR(R = nas, p = 0.99, method="historical")`, so it takes in value `x`, but still calculate VaR of the whole `nas`, and it does that >7000 times, hence it takes forever.

Comment: @huge, if this has answered your question, you can consider accepting the answer and this answer will be useful for other users. see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17878/thanking-users-who-answered-my-question